# Аналог unset($array[i]); только чтобы "закрыл дырку".

Tags: массивы, php

Может быть кто нибудь помнит какая функция в PHP удаляет элемент массива а потом пересчитывает `числовые` ключи чтобы не было дырок?

P.S> Массив числовой двумерный:

```
$def_news = array(
   0 => array('1 Cентября 2013', 'Рады вам представить наш ассортимент!'),
   1 => array('9 Cентября 2013', 'Добро пожаловать! У нас заработал сайт.'),
   2 => array('12 Cентября 2013', 'Заработала галерея.')
);
```

нужно удалить скажем:

```
1 => array('9 Cентября 2013', 'Добро пожаловать! У нас заработал сайт.')
```

и чтобы стало:

```
0 => array('1 Cентября 2013', 'Рады вам представить наш ассортимент!'),
1 => array('12 Cентября 2013', 'Заработала галерея.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

```
array_splice($array, $index, 1);
```

Comment: Благодарю!!!